# Is it possible to make a read only directory in windows XP?

Tags: windows, permissions, directory

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549 the read only attribute is typically used for reasons other than marking a folder as actually read-only.  Therefore it seems to me that it is not possible to make a directory read only in the same sense as linux using
chmod a-w.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote: chmod a-r makes it impossible for anyone to read, not the other way around... I think what you were aiming for was chmod 0444

Comment: Monoxide, I think the command he was aiming for was "chmod a-w". Your command gives read permissions where they might not have existed before, and it removes execute permissions, which are essential for directories if you want to traverse them.

Comment: Rob, you are right chmod a-w was what i wanted rather than chmod a-r, the question has been corrected.

Comment: The Readonly bit is left for compatibility purposes - use proper NTFS ACLs to do this

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, I didn't know that! I just tried it, you can set the readonly attribute on a folder with the `attrib` command, but it has no effect.

The only alternative I see is setting the access rights to the directory based on the user account, if it is on an NTFS formatted drive. Have a look at the [Xcacls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) tool from Microsoft.

Take care though, access permissions on NTFS are a good deal more complex than unix type access control.
In general it's better to *not allow* a specific kind of access, than to *deny* it. I think this is no longer a problem today, but I remember back on good old NT 4, a freind of mine managed to deny all access to a folder, including the administrator account. He couldn't do anything afterwards, not even delete it...

Comment: If you deny all access, you can "Take Ownership", which will allow you to reset the ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

This is true of the readonly flag. You CAN however use NTFS ACL's to do this. I forget exactly how this is done now, and it will only work for NTFS filesystems, but it's possible.

Relevant links:

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_dewey/...](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_dewey/archive/2004/01/20/60902.aspx)
- http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions.htm

Specifically: http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-setting.htm